# 2008 Honda civic ex remote locks on same fuse as radio?

Tags: honda, locks, fuse

My car was recently broken into and my radio was stolen. As a side effect I noticed that my remote locks are no longer working. I replaced the battery in my key to make sure that was not it but am now wondering if its possible that the radio and the power locks are on the same circuit and therefore are not working because the radio is missing. If not can anyone point me to where to find the fuse for the remote locks?

The power locks, inside the car, work fine and I do get a light on the keychain so im thinking the reciever is not getting power.

Thankss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the remote system is inside of the radio. Without the radio, the system will not work, because it is missing. In order to get it back up and running, you have 2 choices. 
1. Replace the radio with a factory unit (new, or you could go to a salvage yard), then you will have to reprogram the remote to work with the new/different radio.
2. Have an aftermarket remote installed and you can put whatever type of stereo system you want installed in place of the original unit.
If you use the factory unit and need to reprogram the fob, instructions can be easily found on the web.

Comment: I imagine that if you get an aftermarket radio and door lock kit, the instructions would be included in there as well?